# Can't make enums workable across different file/class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, enums

I've created a pretty simple prototype:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Days = { "sunday": 0, "monday": 1, "tuesday": 3, "wednesday": 4,
        "thursday": 5, "friday": 6, "saturday": 7 };
    alert("Day Names Enumerator=" + Days.friday);
</script>
```

The result of execution is:

> Day Names Enumerator=6

Once I moved the enum definition into another file

File1.js:

```
    Days = { "sunday": 0, "monday": 1, "tuesday": 3, "wednesday": 4,
        "thursday": 5, "friday": 6, "saturday": 7 };
```

File2.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="File1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Day Names Enumerator=" + Days.friday);
</script>
```

I've received an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Days is not defined

**Question1**: what is a problem with this approach? I've seen a lot of recommendations regarding enums in JS, but nothing about using them from different files

In the very end, I would like my enum to be a part of the class described in File1:

```
function File1Class(){
    this.prototype.Days2 = { "sunday": 0, "monday": 1, "tuesday": 3, "wednesday": 4,
        "thursday": 5, "friday": 6, "saturday": 7 };
}
```

and use it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="File1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Day Names Enumerator=" + File1Class.Days2.friday);
</script>
```

But I still received pretty similar error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'friday' or undefined

**Question2:** How to use enum defined inside of the class? Again, I've seen a lot of recommendations regarding enums and classes in JS, but nothing about using them both

Please advise, any feedback is welcome.

Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDIT:**

Why you guys don't make answers? That would help for all (I believe, at least I will be able to vote and reward you somehow).

With regards to the 1st question: I've added 'var' declaration before the 'Days' and that allowed to access its values from another file.

Thanks a lot!

With regards to the 2nd one: it looks like I should move Days2 declaration out of the class constructor to make it executed. I did that: put it before class declaration, after... but still can't even call it from the class itself:

```
File1Class.prototype.Days2 = { "sunday": 0, "monday": 1, "tuesday": 3, "wednesday": 4,
    "thursday": 5, "friday": 6, "saturday": 7 };
function File1Class(value) {
    this.value = value;
    alert(1);
    alert("<b>From class internals:</b> " + File1Class.prototype.Days2.friday + "<br />");
```

The error is still the same:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'friday' or undefined

Please advise! Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: FWIW, I replicated what you did to get the first failure, and it worked here. Namely, I put

    Days = { "sunday": 0, "monday": 1, "tuesday": 3, "wednesday": 4,
        "thursday": 5, "friday": 6, "saturday": 7 };

in a separate File1.js, and I still got the alert.

Comment: Are you missing the `var` in front of `Days`? i.e. `var Days = { /* etc */ }`

Comment: Furthermore, since `File1Class` hasn't been run, setting `Days2` in the prototype won't have been done. Looks like you've almost got the idea, just a little confused around the edges ;)

Comment: There's something else wrong with `File2.html` because your example will work fine if you don't have some other error that you likely aren't disclosing to us.  Please remember that all global variables should be explicitly declared with the `var` in front of them as in `var Days = ...`.

Comment: By the way, there is no day 2 (apparently). `Days` goes from `monday:1` to `tuesay:3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "EDIT" section of the answer I've answered to the question 1, for consistency purpose it is:

**"var" should be used to define any global variable (thanks to Stoive and jfriend00 for the suggestion)**

With regards to the 2nd question: I had another syntax problem in my class file, once it was fixed the proper solution (again, suggested by Stoive) helped:

**declaration should not be put into constructor, it should be declared earlier to be executed.**

Many thanks to all!